# Grails: running test-app grails uninstall lesscss plugin

Tags: testing, grails, grails-plugin

I'm using Grails to build an application, I have a problem...
I've installed the lesscss to manage the css, but each time I try to test my application with **test-app** command, it uninstalls the plugin. Why is that happening?

```
grails> test-app :integration
| Uninstalled plugin [lesscss]
| Compiling 40 source files
```

I'm very confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin dependency is probably not included anymore in either BuildConfig.groovy or application.properties.

Comment: mmmm it sounds strange because I've also others plugin installed in my application, but also them aren't in the BuildConfig.groovy and application.properties...

Comment: Plugin dependencies should be declared in one of these two files. How did you install the plugins?

Comment: Then the plugin should have been added to the application.properties file.